# cannot convert argument 8 from 'int' to 'cv::HOGDescriptor::HistogramNormType'

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv 4.1. for computing hog descriptors. Here is the constructor of hog:

```
HOGDescriptor hog(Size(20,20),
                  Size(8,8),
                  Size(4,4),
                  Size(4,4),
                  9,
                  1,
                  -1,
                  0, //this argument causes the compiling error
                  0.2,
                  0,
                  64,
                  1);
```

It gives the error:

> C2664: 'cv::HOGDescriptor::HOGDescriptor(const cv::HOGDescriptor &)': cannot convert argument 8 from 'int' to 'cv::HOGDescriptor::HistogramNormType'

What is the problem with the argument 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`HOGDescriptor()`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d33/structcv_1_1HOGDescriptor.html#a5c8e8ce0578512fe80493ed3ed88ca83) you'll see that the 8th argument needs to be of type [`HOGDescriptor::HistogramNormType`](http://HOGDescriptor::HistogramNormType). The error message also indicates this.

The default value for this parameter is `HOGDescriptor::L2Hys`. Using this should remove the error.

Note that using the same parameters in python would not give this error, but C++ will flag this as a compiler error.